# PHP - What are the correct headers for downloading file?

Tags: php, header, download

I have a piece of code that allow users download file from server (document such as docs,docx,pdf etc).

Users can download files but it has some errors like the files were broken. For example, a MS Word file after download need to recovery to read content.

I wonder that if there is any mistake in this code (or problem when uploading?).

```
$size_of_file = filesize($download_path);
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=' . $file_name);
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
header('Pragma: public');
header('Content-Length: ' . $size_of_file);
//read file from physical path
readfile($download_path);
```

[image]

Comment: You could try generating a content-type depending on the file type, instead of using always "octet-stream". Another comment: Try removing the "file transfer" header. I have done what you want in several projects and I have never user such a header.

Comment: does your readfile() method print the contents of your files? you should write them with the echo() command.

Comment: @belgther - readfile() always print file content to stdout. Back to question, maby you print something (space, newline etc) before readfile and it breaks downloaded file? It's possible because file is ok after recovery.

Comment: @piotrekkr I found the root of the problem, I hav some extra spaces after php close tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the root of the problem, I hav some extra spaces after php close tag. Thank you guys.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try like this ?

```
<?php
    header("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-word");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; Filename=SaveAsWordDoc.doc");
?>
```

Comment: I found the root of the problem, I hav some extra spaces after php close tag.